# Find the norm of the matrix in Gauss-Seidel method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let's consider the system
$$
\begin{cases}
3x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3} & =5,\\
2x_{1}+5x_{2}-2x_{3} & =1,\\
2x_{1}-x_{2}+6x_{3} & =7.
\end{cases}
$$
The Gauss-Seidel method is an iterative process: 
$$
X_{k}=TX_{k-1}+C,
$$
where 
$$
T=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 5 & 0\\
2 & -1 & 6
\end{array}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$
My question: do we have a way to find $\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{\infty}$
without finding $T$ explicitly? I ask this question since in practice
by calculating the error by hand, we need to find the norm $\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{\infty}$.
It's quite time-consuming to first find $T$, then evaluate $\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{\infty}$.
If we have a formula for $\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{\infty}$ associated
with the coefficient matrix, it will save time.

Thanks.

Comment: $\|T\|_\infty$ depends on the coefficients of $T$. If you're not given $T$, then you must be given something equivalent to $T$ to calculate its norm. Secondly, why do you need $\|T\|_\infty$? In many cases, the Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\sum_{ij}T_{ij}^2$, or simply an upper estimate of $\|T\|$ is enough.

Comment: I mean, from the coefficient matrix of the system, do we have a practical way to find $\|T\|_\infty$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by $\|T\|_\infty$? Is it defined from $\|Tx\|_\infty\le c\|x\|_\infty$? And why do you need it? Gauss-Seidel does not necessarily need it.